# Cannot execute DROP EXTENSION in a read-only transaction (drop extension if exists google_insights)

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm using Google Cloud SQL (Postgres) and created read replica for my DB.

Now I see in logs such an error:

```
2021-01-16 12:02:46.393 UTC [93149]: [9-1] db=cloudsqladmin,user=cloudsqladmin ERROR:  cannot execute DROP EXTENSION in a read-only transaction

2021-01-16 12:02:46.393 UTC [93149]: [10-1] db=cloudsqladmin,user=cloudsqladmin STATEMENT:  drop extension if exists google_insights;
```

These errors repeat constantly - exactly 120 errors every single hour.

As I understand the Google Cloud tries to drop some of its custom extensions for Postgres and can't do that because replica is read only.

Does anyone know why it happens and how to fix that?

Comment: What exact version of PostgreSQL (9.6,10,11,12,13) is your Cloud SQL hosting? How exactly did you create the replica (gsutil, Cloud Console, API call)? Please run `select * from pg_extension` on your master to get the extensions you have installed and share the [flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags) configured on the master to attempt a reproduction of the issue. If you delete the read replica and attempt to create a new one with `gcloud sql instances create [REPLICA_NAME] --master-instance-name=[MASTER_INSTANCE_NAME] --verbosity debug` do you get any warning or error?

Comment: Postgres 12.
I've created replica using GCP Console web interface - button "Create read replica".
Extensions on my MASTER:
14038,plpgsql,10,11,false,1.0,,

I've just talked with GCP support in chat - they've asked very similar questions and advised to delete replica and create a new one with command you wrote. Looks like some standard support script. Anyway I've done it and watching for the result. It seems that errors stopped, but it's very interesting to know what it was...

Comment: GCP support response:
Our Cloud SQL engineers are still fixing the 'Query Insight' feature of Cloud SQL instances which allows more telemetry and hints in optimizing query performance. 

For now, please perform the either of the following before creating the read-replica:
A. Kindly create a new PostgreSQL instance with the 'Query Insight' section unchecked.
B. Update the instance by clicking 'EDIT' and disabling the 'Query Insight' configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is caused by an issue with the Query Insight feature (in order to avoid getting this error message, simply avoid enabling the Query Insight feature when creating the master and the read replica).

I created the [following issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/177975041) on your behalf that I recommend you to star and follow to check all the relevant updates from the Cloud SQL product team.